# Using scss to change default Vuetify 3 component settings does not work?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

So I've been trying to follow Vuetifys documentation to change up the text-field border.

As far as I understood, the text-field border is determined by `$text-field-border-radius`. I've created a `settings.scss` file in my `src`:

```
@forward 'vuetify/settings' with (
  $text-field-border-radius: 100px,
);
```

I've then added the file to my `vite.config.js`:

```
vuetify({
  autoImport: true,
  styles: { configFile: 'src/settings.scss' }
}),
```

Furthermore I've added this to my `logincomponent.vue` (in the text-field resides):

```
<template>
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="email"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Your e-mail "
                    variant="outlined"
                    outlined
                    color="black"
                    style="color: #FFFFFF"
                    rounded
                    class="text-field-border-radius"
                    required
                  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@use '../settings.scss';

.text-field-border-radius {
  $text-field-border-radius: settings.$text-field-border-radius;
}
</style>
```

Unfortunately nothing I do changes the border radius, and at this point I'm out of ideas. Would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit/overwrite the css in the settings file itself like this.

```
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
  // $utilities: false,
  $color-pack: false,
  $heading-font-family: $head,
  $body-font-family: $body
);
```

Comment: Yes but how would I only change this for a single component instead of overwriting it globally?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a div with the class `v-field__outline` is rendered which contains three divs that make up the outline for a `v-text-field` in Vuetify 3.

`v-field__outline__start`,
`v-field__outline__notch`, and
`v-field__outline__end`

Adding border radius to the start and the end solved this for me.

```
<style scoped>
:deep() .v-field__outline__start {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
:deep() .v-field__outline__end {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
```